# Access container on second Docker host by name with overlay network

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have two Linux machines (`host1` and `host2`) running Docker in swarm mode and configured an overlay network by running:

```sh
host1:$ docker network create -d overlay --attachable appnet
```

`host1` is my manager there I have a web server and connected it to the network above:

```sh
host1:$ docker run --name web --network appnet --rm -d -p 8000:80 nginx
```

On `host2` I created a simple container to test some connectivity:

```sh
host2:$ docker run -dit --network appnet --name alp1 alpine ash
host2:$ docker exec -it alp1 ash
```

Pinging the `web` container by name works fine:

```
# ping web -c 2
PING web (10.0.2.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.777 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.473 ms
```

`wget` with the IP address of `host1` also works:

```
# wget -O out <host1-ip>:8000
Connecting to <host1-ip>:8000 (<host1-ip>:8000)
...
```

But when I try to `wget` by container name the connection times out:

```
# wget -O out web
Connecting to web (10.0.2.2:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.0.2.2): Operation timed out
```

Does someone know why this is happening? I would have expected this to work as I thought the whole point of connecting containers over overlays was to not have to publish a dozen ports.

Comment: im going to guess and say you have a firewall issue that needs resolving. everything looks fine and should work as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

The overlay network is a virtual network that all nodes in your swarm can communicate across. Containers that are associated with one of these networks get an IP address that belongs to that network which is different than the IP address of the host it's running on.

The only way your GET request to `<host1-ip>:8000` would work would be if you exposed that port on the host. That's how traffic external to the swarm can hit one of your containers.

What you really want is a service.

```sh
# Get rid of your container named web on host1
host1:$ docker kill web

# Create a new service on a manage node named web that attaches to your network
host1:$ docker service create --name web --network appnet nginx

yqigiyn9yqhxqcw74voe0tdcg
overall progress: 1 out of 1 tasks
1/1: running   [==================================================>]
verify: Service converged
```

At this point, you can reach the nginx container from any of the nodes on the port that it exposes (80 by default).

```sh
host2:$ curl http://web:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...
</html>
```

You can definitely get this working imperatively with the docker cli, but you'll have a much easier time managing changes and configuration if you look at docker compose. It's a declarative way of setting all of the switches and options you'll need for managing a service.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me still. If there is no replica of the `nginx` service running on `host2` the request times out. It is very strange to me as service discovery appears to be working.

Comment: What's the output from `docker service ls`?